# Getting div url with vs 2013 webbrowser

Tags: html, vba, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I have html code below and i want to get url of a href with vb web browser. I use  Element.GetAttribute("href").ToString() but it gets nothing instead of new blank line. Could you help me to solve this.

```html
<div class="_4bl9 _5yjp">
  <a href="/WingChunLegends/videos/10153914712308760/" target="_blank" id="u_2a_1f">
    <span class="_24-s">Ip Man 3 Trailer USA</span>
  </a>
  <div class="_2rm4">
    <div class="fsl fwn fcb">
      <span>The Legend Will Rise Again</span>
      <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span>
      Video
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#u_2a_1f').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Or if you don't want to use a click event, you could do it like:

```
$(document).ready({
    $("#u_2a_1f").attr("href")
});
```

Hope it helps you!